# VK iOS SDK авторизация

Tags: ios, vkontakte-api

Пытаюсь подключить VK iOS SDK к проекту на swift. Вроде все подключил,но при попытке авторизоваться выводит ошибку.

> 2015-09-17 16:25:26.357 VMusic[2097:118586] -canOpenURL: failed for URL: "vkauthorize://authorize" - error: "(null)"

Но, при повторной попытке авторизоваться,все получается.

Вот код:

AppDelegate.swift

```
 func application(application: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: AnyObject) -> Bool {
    let wasHandled:Bool = VKSdk.processOpenURL(url, fromApplication: sourceApplication)
    return wasHandled
}
```

ViewController.swift

```
//
//  ViewController.swift
//  VMusic
//
//  Created by Kair on 10.08.15.
//  Copyright © 2015 Kair Omarov. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

extension ViewController: VKSdkDelegate {
    func vkSdkNeedCaptchaEnter(captchaError: VKError) { }
    func vkSdkTokenHasExpired(expiredToken: VKAccessToken) { }
    func vkSdkUserDeniedAccess(authorizationError: VKError) { }
    func vkSdkShouldPresentViewController(controller: UIViewController) { }
    func vkSdkReceivedNewToken(newToken: VKAccessToken) { }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let SCOPE = [ "friends", "audio"];

    @IBAction func logInBtn(sender: AnyObject) {

        if (VKSdk.wakeUpSession()) {



             print("Все ок!;)")

            let audioReq: VKRequest = VKRequest(method: "audio.get", andParameters: ["owner_id": "156137693", "count":"3"], andHttpMethod: "GET")

            audioReq.executeWithResultBlock(
                {
                    (response) -> Void in

                    let audios =  response.json as! NSDictionary
                    let audiosCount = audios["count"]!
                    print("У пользователя \(audiosCount) аудиозаписей")
                    let tracks = audios["items"] as! NSArray
                    let firstTrack = tracks[0]
                    let firstTrackAuthor = firstTrack["artist"]!
                    let firstTrackName = firstTrack["title"]!
                    print("И первый трек \(firstTrackAuthor!) - \(firstTrackName!)")




                }, errorBlock: {
                    (error) -> Void in
                    print(error)


                })

        } else {
            print("ошибка здесь")
        }

    }



    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
         //VK AppID 4659165

        VKSdk.initializeWithDelegate(self, andAppId: "4659165")

        let wakeUpSession = VKSdk.wakeUpSession()
        print(wakeUpSession)
        let isLogged = VKSdk.isLoggedIn()
        if isLogged == true {

            print("Пользователь авторизован")


        } else if isLogged == false {

            print("Пользователь не авторизован")
            VKSdk.authorize(SCOPE);
            VKSdk.authorize(SCOPE);

        }

    }




    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

Bridging Header

```
//
//  Use this file to import your target's public headers that you would like to expose to Swift.
//

#import <VKSdk/VKSdk.h>
```

Answer (score 1):

а Вы добавили в Info.plist для iOS 9? https://github.com/VKCOM/vk-ios-sdk

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
    <string>vkauthorize</string>
</array>
```

Comment: Да,почему-то на устройстве с первого раза все ок